# Kubernetes dashboard gives "Unauthorized" when using proxy

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to work with a Kubernetes dashboard on a newly set up AKS cluster with Kubernetes 1.9.9 deployed on Azure.

I run `kubectl proxy` and open http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy/#!/overview?namespace=default to look at the dashboard.

I get a message `Unauthorized`. And almost all functionality is disabled.

When I google this problem most solutions seem to revolve around not going against anything *but* `localhost` to reach the dashboard. But I *am* going against `localhost`. Isn't `kubectl proxy` supposed to give me an automatically authorized entry point?

Comment: You use cert or token in ~/.kube/config for connection to cluster?

Comment: Maybe you cert or token not access to kube-system namespace?

Comment: I've used `az aks get-credentials` to retrieve credentials (it's an azure aks cluster). It seems that it adds both `token` and `client-certificate-data`, `client-key-data` to ´~/.kube/config`. Also, I have no trouble at all accessing the cluster from command line.

Comment: have you seen the authorization prompt at all? Like in this [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control) ?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what `ServiceAccount` or `User` you are using to connect to the kube-apiserver. If you really want to have access without looking at policies in detail (gives access to everything), you can `kubectl apply -f` something like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: my-cluster-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: <your-user-from-your-~/.kube/config>
```

Alternatively:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding my-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=<your-user-from-your-~/.kube/config>
```

You can also use a `Group` or `ServiceAccount` in place of a `User`.

Comment: Ok, so I tried something very similar before and for some reason it didn't work. Now it did. I suspect that there was either some misconfiguration somewhere or the dashboard pod needs to be deleted (and automatically recreated) for this settings to have effect.

Comment: I wonder though: What are the risks associated with this configuration when using `kubectl proxy`? The dashboard isn't typically exposed to the outside world. Obviously these rules are a bad idea if the dashboard service is exposed though the loadbalancer. I don't see the use case for that though.

Comment: Generally, it's pretty secure unless someone hacks your client, in this case, your laptop.

Comment: Great, my understanding too.